# Minimize button won't appear on MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I am having trouble adding the minimise button to my MFC Dialog application. I have enabled minimise box (true).

The minimise button appears in the designer view but when I run the application the buttons are not visible.

**Other settings are:**
Style: Overlapped
Application Window: True
Border: Dialog Frame
Tool Window: False
System Menu: True

I tried adding:
    **ModifyStyle(0, WS_MINIMIZEBOX, TRUE);**

to the **OnInitDialog()** but hasn't solved it.

There are 3 styles that I can choose which are popup, child and overlapped. If I use popup I don't see a title bar and cannot drag the window. Child throws an access violation if I use that style, so the only style I can choose is overlapped which shows the title bar and allows me to drag the window but the minimise button is not visible.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and running Windows 10 1809.

I have double checked and minimise box is set to TRUE however it still won't show up on the dialog box when running.

The problem is when I use the Popup window style, I do not see the title bar at all! Also if I use the popup style I am unable to drag the window (title bar is missing). Overlapped seems the only style that I can use.

Comment: I only have 3 options: popup, child or overlapped. I tried all three different styles and none have the buttons. Could you give me a hint where I would set WS_MINIMIZEBOX style? Thank you.

Comment: In the resource editor, select the main dialog box and then, in the Properties window, scroll to find the "Minimize Box" property and set it to "true". And, normally, a dialog is a "Popup" window.

Comment: The problem is when I use Popup window I do not see the title bar at all!

Comment: Is it a dialog-based application or a dialog box that is activated *inside* the application?

Comment: dialog based application. Its a program that parses emails and the dialog based option looked better than the other types because it had minimal toolbars etc.

Comment: So, can you open/edit the dialog resource in the resource editor? If so, select it and set the styles you want from the list given in the "Properties" window.

Comment: yes I can open the dialog resource and view the properties. I have been doing this from the beginning. I have checked the settings but nothing seems to make the minimise button visible. Perhaps its a bug with the designer or I am missing something.

Comment: Try `WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX `

Comment: That is not required. Just make sure your dialog template has the appropriate styles. We don't know because you failed to show your dialog template resource script.

Comment: @IInspectable, What, exactly, is not required ?  My suggestion above is to add a few styles.  That solved the problem for the OP, regardless of where he added them.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ModifyStyle(0, WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, TRUE);
    ...
}
```

Consider modifying your dialog template (in the .RC file) to include the necessary style bits instead of modifying the style at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

MFC is no different from programming a dialog without any frameworks. You declare a `DIALOGEX` resource, and have the system load it up, and display a dialog based on that template.

To get a dialog with a minimize box it needs at least the styles `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` and `WS_SYSMENU`<sup>1</sup>. Open up the .rc script that defines the `DIALOGEX` dialog template, and make sure those 2 styles are present in the `STYLE` element.

A default dialog template for a dialog-based application (with a minimize box) will typically be defined like this:

```
IDD_MFCAPPLICATION1_DIALOG DIALOGEX  0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SHELLFONT | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
 | WS_THICKFRAME
 | WS_SYSMENU
 | WS_MINIMIZEBOX
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION ""
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,209,179,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14
    CTEXT           "TODO: Place dialog controls here.",IDC_STATIC,10,96,300,8
END
```

You don't need to write *any* code that executes at runtime to get this behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup> *From [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles):* "`WS_MINIMIZEBOX`: The window has a minimize button. [...] **The `WS_SYSMENU` style must also be specified.**"

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnInitDialog(){

ModifyStyle(0, WS_MINIMIZEBOX, TRUE);
ModifyStyle(0, WS_POPUP, TRUE);
ModifyStyle(0, WS_BORDER, TRUE);
ModifyStyle(0, WS_SYSMENU, TRUE);
ModifyStyle(0, WS_CAPTION, TRUE);
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24958724)